# Дата больше 365 дней

Tags: дата, php

Здравствуй ХешКод, у меня возник вопрос как вывести кол-во оставшихся дней?

```
Есть дата начала: 1370196236
И дата окончания: 1401732236

echo date("d", $enddate - $begindate);
```

И мне почему-то выводит 01, хотя должен вывести 365, скажите как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1370196236 - это timestamp (количество секунд от 01.01.1970 по Гринвичу).

Количество дней узнайте математически: разницу поделить на 86400 (60(секунд в минуте) * 60(минут в часе) * 24(часов в дне)).

Comment: Спасибо, не знал :)

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Советую прочитать про этот timestamp, что бы не иметь проблем с временными зонами и т.д. :)